# Unable to check/uncheck radio button inside accordion widget

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

I am unable to check/uncheck a radio button inside Accordion widget.

Here is my code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });   
</SCRIPT> 

<div id="accordion" >
    <input type="radio" id="worddoc"  name="submissionType">Upload Word
    <div>
        <input type="file"/>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="pdfdoc" name="submissionType">Upload Pdf
    <div>
        <input type="file"/>             
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            $(function() {
                $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
            });   
  </SCRIPT> 

<div id="accordion" >
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="worddoc"  name="submissionType"> Upload Word
        <input type="file"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="pdfdoc" name="submissionType">Upload Pdf
        <input type="file"/>             
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks,Its not working all div content is displaying..It should work as Accordion concept.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add headers for each accordion option, like so:

```
<div id="accordion" >
    <h1>Option 1</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="worddoc"  name="submissionType" /> Upload Word
        <input type="file"/>
    </div>
    <h1>Option 2</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="pdfdoc" name="submissionType" />Upload Pdf
        <input type="file"/>             
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRPw9/). Let me know if this is not what you mean.